# Running various Shiny Apps in the same RStudio Server session

Tags: shiny

I haven't found much information about this problem. In the Administrator's Guide http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/ says:

> Shiny Server can manage R processes running various Shiny applications over different URLs and ports.

But I can't find where to host two apps in different ports in the same machine. In the RStudio session I have on the server machine, it gets "blocked" if I run 1 app. But how could I manage running 2 different apps? Running 2 RStudio server version on the same machine?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody answered, I post what I found several days after:

- One solution is to open a shell and use the commands "R ..." or "Rstudio ..." depending on the system, in order to run whatever script you want.
- Another solution (what I finally did) was to set a webpage with a navbarPage and 2 tabPanel's.

Thank you